# PHP.INI reading sequence

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have following idea - add some changed values configuration lines on top (or bootom) of php.ini file, so I keep original values untouched. Where should I put them. Is this order same with other Linux config files.

PHP.INI file

```
[PHP]
; My changed configuration lines before original php.ini settings
expose_php = Off

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

last variable value rules

```
[PHP]
; My changed configuration lines before original php.ini settings
expose_php = Off
expose_php = On
```

so it `On`

Variables will be overwritten successively in left-to-right order, with the rightmost one winning the hand every time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: if this is the answer, can you mark it so other will get use it also, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. With best regards.